# Is there a better word than "just" for describing the recency of an event?

Tags: synonyms

So, in the US, we make ample use of the word "just" in a context such as:
"I just finished my homework." (I finished my homework very recently -- perhaps immediately preceding this statement)  or
"He had just gotten his driver's license when his father's car was stolen." (pointing out that there was very little [if any] time between the two events)
I only recently learned that this is, apparently, an Americanism.  Is there a better, more universally accepted way of expressing this?
I feel that "recently" is not quite "recent" enough.

Comment: It's an Americanism? Why do you think this? I just went to the Cambridge Dictionaries Online website (to try to verify your statement) and look what I saw there: *"We have just added an English–Spanish/Spanish–English bilingual dictionary to Cambridge Dictionaries Online!"*

Comment: I think "just" is heavily overused. Maybe I'm sensitive to it because I hear "just two?" at restaurants all the time.

Comment: @Robert: for me "just one" -all- the time.

Comment: "Just one" is somewhat understandable, albeit no less tacky. I have to wonder, at what number do they drop the "just?"

Answer (score 5):

For the past perfect tense you have a few options:

- **scarcely**: "They had scarcely made this resolve when a feeble cry arose from a dark object that floated rapidly by." -- Edgar Allan Poe, *The Narrative of Arthur Gordon Pym*.
- **barely**: "We had barely completed this work when the Commander, the Captain, Marvin, Borup, and Esquimos came in." -- Matthew A. Henson, *Matthew A. Henson's Historic Arctic Journey*.
- **hardly**: "...but he had hardly reached home when Frank, who had been sent after him, delivered this note..." -- James Boswell, *The Life of Samuel Johnson*.

Answer (score 2):

The only *Americanism* I see in the sentences you cite is the use of *just* with the Past Simple. In British English, *just* is usually used with the Present Perfect tense, which is considered the correct thing to do according to grammar books.

As for another word to replace *just*, I can't think of one, *just* describes exactly what you want to express.

Comment: +1, but not so much 'the correct thing to do according to grammar books', as the thing that is done by British English speakers. (And most British linguists don't recognize a present perfect tense.)

Comment: Aren't British English speakers influenced by the American use of the language, esp with words used so often? I have the feeling they are... It's the only reason I've cited the grammar books.

Comment: *just* could be replaced with *recently*, or in some cases *newly* as in `The just-hatched chicks crowded the nest and made an awful lot of noise` -> `The newly-hatched chicks crowded the nest...` ...Not sure you can do this in all situations, but probably in many.

Comment: @Irene: Google Ngrams [confirms](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+just+finished%2C+I+have+just+finished&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) that *just* is usually used with the present perfect in the U.K. (at least until just recently).  This used to be the case in the U.S. as well, but that started changing around 1920. Strangely, *recently* doesn't follow the same rule.

Comment: Can you give an example of 'just' used with those tenses?

Comment: British: "I have just finished." American: "I just finished." (Americans also say "I have just finished", but usually only when there is another reason to use that tense, and not just because they used *just*.)

Comment: I see, now, that I was mistaken regarding the "Americanism" part of my post.  That is quite relieving!  And I mean "quite" in the American sense.  The difference between the American and British usage of "just" is, indeed, just a matter of tense.

Answer (score 0):

"We had sat down [only] moments before the remaining guests arrived".

"He had been shot that very minute".

"Seconds before, we had witnessed the strangest scene unfolding before us".

"A few moments ago, our lives were changed forever".

"We only got in three minutes ago".